# Mesh deforms when i try to merge 2 parts

Tags: mesh

So I was following a tutorial when I suddenly came across a mistake I probably made.
When I try to connect the hand to the body the connected area moves straight through the body. I've tried everything I can think of to fix the problem. I am pretty much lost right now. Can anybody help? I am working on Bender 2.80.75.[image]

Comment: I would appreciate to see your blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ but have you tried to disable Mirror modifier before Bridge loop?

Comment: This is almost certainly an issue with the Mirror modifier. But in exactly what way I am not yet sure, as I cannot duplicate your issue. But I've had the same thing happen to me before. Typically, when you join your hand mesh to the body mesh, the hand mesh will inherit your body's Mirror modifier and automatically appear on the other side of the mesh, ready to be merged. If that didn't happen, something is wrong. Try rejoining your hand mesh to the body mesh (make sure the hand mesh has no modifiers on it first). Select the body LAST, then Ctrl-J to join the meshes. Then merge vertices.

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem. I tried turning off the mirror modifier. I noticed that the hand is mirrored on the y-axis and the body is mirrored at the x-axis. Maybe that is causing the problem? Because I modeled the hand separately and joined it to the body. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Now I noticed - Mirror modifier is disabled for edit mode, means you should not see mirror in X, but you do. So it looks like you duplicate already mirrored mesh.

Comment: Ctrl+A Rotation ?

Comment: Okay! I found the problem. The two things have not been mirrored on the same axis. So I separated them again and I deleted the ''wrong'' side and applied the modifier again. It worked. Thank you so much for that tip.